# Power cable for 5V 20A power supply?

Tags: power-supply, power, switch-mode-power-supply

I bought a switching power dupply (SMPS) rated at 5V | 20A | 100W. 
[image: Power Supply]

But it seems I don't understand how power supply works. I need total of 18A on output, but that seems to be over the limit of standard 16A | 220V wall outlet's limit.

How would I power this supply without burning my house down? I bought fuses and relays but that can only handle max at 10A.

---

Reason for such high amperage needed:

I was going to power 300 LEDs that require 5v 60mA per LED. 
I'm planning to make it in 2 parallel structure, giving me 150 leds each side. It turns out I need 5v each side with 9A flowing each side, totaling 18A.
So does two 9A merge on outlet's side?

Comment: ... What's 5V times 18A? What's 220V times 16A?

Comment: 18A at 5V is 90W. Which is about half an Amp from 220V outlet.

Comment: It will consume ~0.5 A on the primary (mains) side att full load. Up to 10 A/mm^2 is fine heating-wise, but you will be limited by maximum allowed voltage drop in your 5 V system.

Comment: Oh....! I only needed to consider the wattage...? Then I dont need 12AWG that can handle 20A....? Oh gosh I feel so stupid :'(

Comment: @Sysnaptic You need to consider the high current on the output, of course and use the proper cable.

Comment: @Eugene Sh Yes sir!

Comment: English tip: Twice you wrote "brought" when I think you meant "bought".  Otherwise your English is very good.

Comment: Haha yes, 'bought' was what I was trying to say. I always get that two mixed up. Thank you! Hehe

Comment: @Sysnaptic Note that you **do** need heavy wires capable of supporting 20A on the 5V side!

Comment: @marcelm if im dividing into two section that outputs 9A on each side, i only need cable capable of handling only 9A correct?

Comment: @Sysnaptic What if there's a short circuit? Then the full 20A (or even more!) can be pulled through the thinner cables. They need to sustain that until short-circuit protection (if any) kicks in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only draw 90 watts from the supply, it will only draw perhaps 100 watts from the AC source - a power supply passes power (voltage times current), not just voltage or just amperage. (The "extra" input power is lost, usually as heat,  due to inefficiency in the conversion process).

Comment: Thank you for the comment! Now I understand it only pulls 100W / 220V = 0.5A

Comment: nitpicking: a switching power supply, or a transformer, transfer power. A linear power supply does keep current constant, and heats up quite a bit in the process.

Comment: I'd say a linear power supply does transfer power, but with less efficiency than a plain transformer or a switching supply.  If you have a 12 volt 20 amp linear supply, it certainly won't draw anything near 20 amps at 120 or 240 volts AC input.

Comment: A linear voltage regulator does draw as much current as it delivers, but a linear power supply will have a transformer before the linear regulator - the transformer will do the voltage/current conversion and deliver an appropriate voltage to the input of the regulator.